# Can I disable "high contrast" mode in Internet Explorer despite high contrast being enabled in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, accessibility

I'm using a Windows 8 high-contrast theme. The problem is that I use Internet Explorer 10 for testing website design, so I need high-contrast to be turned off in Internet Explorer only. Is there a way to turn off high-contrast in Internet Explorer 10 while high-contrast is enabled in system-wide Windows 8 settings?

Comment: Don't think so. If high-contrast mode is what I think it is (the accessibility option), it alters the color profile of the display all together. But you did said theme so if you were to provide the theme's name or a link to it, it would help those that want to answer this.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Fortunately, no, it doesn't alter the color profile of the entire system. If you go to `Personalization` in the `Control Panel` of Windows 8 and scroll to the bottom, you'll see a few "high contrast" themes provided by Windows 8. I'm using one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Open up IE.  Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.  It reloads IE and takes the high contrast setting off.  You can do the same toggle to turn it back on if so desired.  However, I find, due to the way webpages are created, using high contrast isn't really useful...I only want it for the actual system.

Comment: `Alt+Left` and what is `keyboard shirt+printscreen`? *clarify*, please? shift?

Comment: This disables the contrast mode in Windows.